# Typecasting HashSets in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have two classes where one derives the other. I also have a HashSet field which stores a bunch of Derived classes. The problem is that the Derived class is only used internally and I have a property which needs to return a HashSet of Base classes. I know List has the ConvertAll method, does HashSet have something similar?

```
public class Base
{
}

public class MyClass
{
    private class Derived : Base
    {
    }

    private HashSet<Derived> mList;

    public HashSet<Base> GetList { get { /* Convert mList to HashSet<Base> */ } }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert a `HashSet<Derived>` to a `HashSet<Base>` *without* casting each item.

To explain *why* this is not possible, have a look at the following code example:

```
HashSet<Derived> mySet = ...;
HashSet<Base> x = (HashSet<Base>)mySet;  // imagine this were possible

x.Add(new Base());  // legal code, but cannot work, since x is really a HashSet<Derived>
```

However, since the IEnumerable interface is [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx), the following should be possible:

```
HashSet<Derived> mySet = ...;
IEnumerable<Base> x = mySet;  // works in C# 4

// no problem here, since no items can be added to an IEnumerable
```

Thus, you could change your method declaration:

```
public IEnumerable<Base> GetList { get { return mList; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare mList as...

```
private HashSet<Base> mList;
```

You can do...

```
public HashSet<Base> GetList { get { return new HashSet<Base>(mList); } }
```

Since the mList implements `IEnumerable<Base>`

Comment: I wondered about this but of course if he is using that internally a lot then that's a lot of casting to Derived needed potentially. It might be better just doing a manual ConvertAll method than scattering casts all over the place...

Comment: @Chris I think it would be a bad code smell if that were the case but you're right it is certainly possible.

Comment: The cast isn't really necessary.  `mList` as you have it is already an `IEnumerable<Base>`.

Comment: @Bencr: why do you say its a bad code smell? Presumably he has a HashSet<Derived> because he is doing things with the items in that set? Whether he is using it a lot or a little is a different matter but I can't imagine the amount he is doing it is a smell. Perhaps I'm missing something on why the OP might be using a HashSet<Derived>...

Comment: @Chris, if his base class were `Car` with a `void Drive()` operation and his derived class was `SportsCar` which overrode `Drive` then why cast? If his derived class was something totally different however, which extended the interface like `Plane : Car` with a `Fly()` operation then he'd have to cast when a better design might be to have a base class of `TransportMethod` with a virtual `Travel()` operation. I don't know exactly what he's trying to achieve but I do know I rarely have to box and un-box objects since generics were available.

Comment: @BenCr: I see where you are coming from. I was imagining it was more the case that the reason he was working with his derived class is because he'd put methods like "setUpDerived" or maybe properties that were useful to the base class but made no sense for the parent class. I see where you are coming from now though at least. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible since `HashSet` is not covariant. It implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which is, but that restricts you to creating a *new* `HashSet` from the old one. They won't be kept in sync.